# PHP: I can't do a search in the search field, using the DataTables module 1.10.4

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables

I have a simple table view. I can't do a search for the Product column.

Here my code for datek_h2h.php :

```
    <table id="novaltable" class="table table-bordered table-striped "
            data-toggle="table"
            data-search="true"
            data-search-text=""
            data-filter-control="true" 
            data-show-export="true"
            data-click-to-select="true"
            data-toolbar="#toolbar">
      <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Owner</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php
        $query_datek_h2h=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from testingdata INNER JOIN user ON testingdata.iduser=user.iduser INNER JOIN name ON testingdata.idname=name.idname WHERE testingdata.deleted='no' ");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_datek_h2h)){
          ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['cust_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['product']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['color']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['owner']; ?></td>   
            <td><?php echo $row['inisial']; ?></td>
            <td>
              <a href="#edit_datek_h2h<?php echo $row['iddata']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>  
              <a href="#delete_datek_h2h<?php echo $row['iddata']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
              <?php include ('button_datek_h2h.php'); ?>
            </td>
         </tr>
          <?php
        }
      
      ?>
    </table>
```

I think the error is due to this section, because if this section is deleted, it can be searched in the Product column.

```
<?php include ('button_datek_h2h.php'); ?>
```

I'm using the dropdown in the button_datek_h2h.php file for the Product section.

Here my code for button_datek_h2h.php :

```
<!-- Delete -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="delete_datek_h2h<?php echo $row['iddata']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <center><h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure want to delete ??</h3></center>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                
                <div class="container-fluid">
                
                <!-- Confirmation Delete Table -->
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:120px">Name</td>
                        <td style="width:010px">:</td>
                        <th style="width:200px"><?php echo $row['cust_name']; ?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:120px">Product</td>
                        <td style="width:010px">:</td>
                        <th style="width:200px"><?php echo $row['product']; ?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:120px">Color</td>
                        <td style="width:010px">:</td>
                        <th style="width:200px"><?php echo $row['color']; ?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:120px">Owner</td>
                        <td style="width:010px">:</td>
                        <th style="width:200px"><?php echo $row['owner']; ?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:120px">User</td>
                        <td style="width:010px">:</td>
                        <th style="width:200px"><?php echo $row['inisial']; ?></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
                    <a href="delete_datek_h2h.php?iddata=<?php echo $row['iddata']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</a>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- /.modal -->

<!-- Edit -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="edit_datek_h2h<?php echo $row['iddata']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <center><h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ubah</h4></center>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <form method="POST" action="edit_datek_h2h.php?iddata=<?php echo $row['iddata']; ?>">
                
                    <div style="height:10px;"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <label style="position:relative; top:7px;">Name:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['cust_name']; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div style="height:10px;"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <label style="position:relative; top:7px;">Product:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <?php
                        $query_produk = "SELECT product FROM testingdata";
                        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query_produk);
                        $array = array();
                        while ($row_product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                            $array [ $row_product['product'] ] = $row_product['product'];
                        }
                        ?>
                            <select id="product" name="product" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">-Pilih product-</option>
                        <?php
                            foreach ($array as $product=>$product) {

                                $selected = '';
                                if ($product == $row['product']) {
                                    $selected = 'selected';
                                }
                                echo "<option " . $selected . " value='$product'>$product</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    
                    <div style="height:10px;"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <label style="position:relative; top:7px;">Color:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" name="color" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['color']; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="height:10px;"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <label style="position:relative; top:7px;">User:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" name="inisial" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['inisial']; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Save</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

I hope I can search for all columns.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have "search" key

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#example').DataTable({
     search: {
         return: true,
     },
  });
});
```

[documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/enter_search.html)